# how to insert pandas dataframe into IN operator of SQL

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql

I have pandas dataframe with unique number of user:

```
data_frame = pd.DataFrame({'uniq_num' :['1qw3','2wed','3das','4frr','533ew','612w']})
```

I want to pass this column to sql query where I use IN operator:

```
SELECT users FROM database
where users IN ("here I want to pass my dataframe, so it would search in all rows of my dataframe")
```

I have tried doing this

```
    data_frame = ','.join([str(x) for x in data_frame.iloc[:, 0].tolist()])
```

which would retrun whith this `'1qw3,2wed,3das,4frr,533ew,612w'`

and then something like `WHERE users in STRING_SPLIT(data_frame, ',')` but this one is obviousely doesnt work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the list into a tuple, this will give you the correct format

```
import pandas as pd
data_frame = pd.DataFrame({'uniq_num' :['1qw3','2wed','3das','4frr','533ew','612w']})

in_statement = tuple(data_frame.iloc[:, 0].tolist())
sql = f"""SELECT users FROM database
where users IN {in_statement}"""
```

output sql variable:

```
SELECT users FROM database
where users IN ('1qw3', '2wed', '3das', '4frr', '533ew', '612w')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating SQL query in python then try this,

```
user_ids = "'"+"','".join(data_frame.uniq_num.values)+"'"
query = "SELECT users FROM database "+\
"WHERE users IN ("+user_ids+")"
```